# Separating coroutine generation and execution, ensuring proper closing

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

I feel as if the answer to this should be simple, but I'm having trouble. First, I'll clarify that my understanding is that I want to deal with coroutines and not tasks as, to create a task is to automatically schedule something on the event loop. I just want to pass around coroutines that I can properly order to achieve the desired execution order I want.

That said, the following succeeds without a `Runtime` WARNING due to an un-unawaited coroutine.

```
async def nested_func():
    pass


async def outer_nest():
    await nested_func()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    outer_coroutine = outer_nest()
    outer_coroutine.close()
```

However, the following does NOT

```
async def passed_func():
    pass


async def caller(passed_coroutine):
    await passed_coroutine


if __name__ == '__main__':
    passed_coroutine = passed_func()
    caller_coroutine = caller(passed_coroutine)
    caller_coroutine.close()
```

I think it has to do with the fact that, if `my_async_func` is a coroutine's label, performing `my_async_func()` doesn't analyze the body, just the parameters. So, in the first scenario, the awaitable of `nested_func` isn't even made until the execution phase of `outer_nest`.
In contrast, the latter builds an awaitable, but, since `caller`'s body is never touched, it's left hanging.

Is the only solution to keep a list of awaitables, and call their `close` function if the awaitable's parent function has close called on it? Some sort of manager?

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```py
async def coro():
    pass

print(coro, type(coro))
```

`coro` itself is not a coroutine. It's a function. When you *call* it, it gives you a coroutine.

In your first example, you have only one coroutine which is `outer_coroutine`. This coroutine is closed before the program terminates. So you don't have any coroutine that is not either awaited or closed, therefore you don't see any warning. If you comment out the `.close()` line it shows the warning as well.

In your second example, you have two coroutines: `passed_coroutine` and `caller_coroutine`. Then you closed the `caller_coroutine` but what about the `passed_coroutine`? In fact the warning is for this coroutine:

```
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'passed_func' was never awaited
```

you can close that as well and warnings are gone.

So the warning is not because it analyzed the body of the coroutine, that's because you have un-awaited and not-closed coroutine left.

> Is the only solution to keep a list of awaitables, and call their close function if the awaitable's parent function has close called on it? Some sort of manager?

You normally use coroutines inside asyncio framework. They'll be wrapped in a Task object and scheduled in the event loop. If you create a coroutine you want to use it by "awaiting" it inside another coroutine/task. Later you may want to keep track of Tasks in order to close them gracefully. Honestly I don't have any situation that a bare coroutine is created and not used somehow.

Comment: The circumstances are separating out task generation from task execution and, in particular, writing tests to ensure that the appropriate task list is generated, for which, calling .close on the tasks makes the most sense.